# Read integers from standard input

Tags: c

A simple C problem, I want to read integers from standard input(user input), each line of standard input contains an integer, and an empty line denotes the end of input.
I tried to use gets() and scanf(), but it's not working.

```
while (1){
            char a;
            scanf("%c",&a);
            printf("%c",a);
            if (a=='\r'||a=='\n'){
                break;
            }
        }
```

when i use scanf(), It terminates every time i press an enter;

```
while(1){
            char a[10];
            gets(a);
            if (a=='\r'||a=='\n'){
                break;
            }
        }
```

and when i use gets(), '\r' or '\n' can not be read into buffer, so it never break.

Could anyone help me with that, thanks in advance!

Comment: Never use `gets`.  To read an integer with scanf, use `%d`.

Comment: Mixing `scanf` and `get`/`fgets` doesn't work well. Anyway `scanf` is not at all made for interactive user input. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this an [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You can use `fgets` and `sscanf` to do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[100];
    int number;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
        if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number) != 1) {    // or strtol perhaps
            break;
        }
        printf("Number: %d\n", number);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to read integers from standard input

Doing

> ```
> while (1){
>   char a;
>   scanf("%c",&a);
>   printf("%c",a);
>   if (a=='\r'||a=='\n'){
>     break;
>   }
> }
> ```

you read a line containing any characters, not only a number representation

Doing

> ```
> while(1){
>    char a[10];
>    gets(a);
>    if (a=='\r'||a=='\n'){
>       break;
>    }
> }
> ```

*a* is a `char*` so in `a=='\r'||a=='\n'` you wrongly compare a pointer with characters, you want `*a=='\r'||*a=='\n'`

Additional remarks :

- *never* use *gets*, use *fgets* to read a line, so `fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin)`
- but you still read a line containing any characters, not only a number

> I want to read integers from standard input(user input), each line of standard input contains an integer, and an empty line denotes the end of input.

A proposal, a line containing only space and tabs before the end of line is considered empty, and the spaces and tabs before/after the number are bypassed without being considered invalid :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  while(1) {
    puts("enter number");

    char a[10];

    if (fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin) == NULL) {
      puts("EOF");
      break;
    }

    errno = 0;

    char * endptr;
    long n = strtol(a, &endptr, 10);

    if (errno != 0) {
      puts("not a valid long");
    }
    else {
      /* check possible unexpected characters */
      char * p = endptr;

      for (;;) {
        if (*p == 0) {
          if (endptr == a) {
            puts("done");
            return 0;
          }
          printf("the number is %ld\n", n);
          break;
        }
        if (!isspace(*p++)) {
          puts("not (only) a valid long");
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra n.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter number
123
the number is 123
enter number
 123
the number is 123
enter number
12a
not (only) a valid long
enter number
a12
not (only) a valid long
enter number
a
not (only) a valid long
enter number

done
```

Comment: Do you know why `if(a =='\r' || a == '\n')` `'a'` is receiving `\n`?

Comment: @raijin out of Windows the end of line if only indicated by a \n, there is no \r sent\read, so `a =='\r'` is never true for instance under Linux

Comment: Yes, in text mode the `'\r'` of `"\r\n"` is filtered out.

Comment: Don't quite get it. Isn't it supposed to receive only one char the `a` variable? I tested the OP code with 4 `printf(%c, a)` before the `if` statement and it seems to accumulate with `\n` . The output was : `bbbb\n\n\n`

Comment: @raijin of course if you speak about the first code of the OP _a_ contains only one char, but that char can be \r or \n (or other). There is no accumulation, but several loops. It is not the best place for question/answer here, what about to open a new question ?

Comment: Im banned, cant do that at the moment =/

Comment: @raijin really ? wow ! so you understand now, just looping several time, one char by loop

Comment: @JasperZhou you say that but you accepted the other answer ^^ More seriously happy I helped you. Have nice programming

Comment: i get why ´\n´ stay in stdin and we need to clean, but i dont get why the ´\n´ is stacking with one ´scanf(%c,&a)´ and with multiples ´printf(%c,a)´ everything before the ´if´ condition.

Comment: Also `if(a == '\n')` is true returns true. But isn't `'\n'` has a value of 13? How `a` can support that?

Comment: @raijin the input is blocked until you enter the end of line, that means for instance you hit the letter 'a' then the leter 'b' then the '\n' and only now the program can continue, so _scanf_ gives the 'a' and it is print and loop again, the _scanf_ does not stops and give the character 'b' which is print, loop again, the _scanf_ does not stop and give the \n

Comment: @raijin no \n is classically 10, 13 is classically for \r, there are two different characters

Comment: Yeah you right `\n` is really 10, thanks for the correction. I'm going to save this problem and search for more info in the future about how the compiler works. Sorry for this much trouble.

Comment: @raijin ok, is you are allowed being banned may be upvote my answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think using getline might be a more general solution, here is some example code that you could modify for your purposes, "buf" would contain the input.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    int size;
    unsigned int length;
    size = getline(&buf, &length, stdin);
    if (size != -1)
        /* do anything you want with the stuff that was entered here */
        /* for the example I just write it back to stdout! */
        puts(buf);
    else
        /* this would be your "end" condition */
        printf("Nothing read!\n");

    printf("Size: %d\n Length: %d\n", size, length);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```